# How many moves are at least needed to change the order of cubes to a arbitrary order?

Tags: combinatorics

We have some distinct cubes that are ordered like below:

[image]

How many moves are at least needed to change the order of cubes to a arbitrary order?

valid moves:

in every step we can take a cube and put it on another cube or on the desk.

> 1.$11$
>
> 2.$14$
>
> 3.$17$
>
> 4.$23$
>
> 5.$25$

**My attempt**:If we put all cubes on the desk and then bring them together we will need $17$ moves so every case can be made using $17$ moves.I also got a combination that needs at least $16$ moves because it is a test the answer will be $17$ but I need a complete proof.So my question is which combination needs $17$ moves to be made?

Comment: what is a random order?

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek I think he means "arbitrary". "Think" being the operative word.

Comment: Which order have you found that needs 16? And when you say "we can take a cube and put it on another cube or on the desk" do we have to take a cupe which is on the top, or can we take a cube in the middle (and have all the cubes on top of it follow along)?

Comment: I would probably go for a tower of IKHEDCBAFJ. To achieve that, I have to put everything from every tower somehwere else ( 7 moves) to access their bottoms, than put it everything on I (that makes 10 moves). All assuming I understand the question correctly.

Comment: @Arthur Yes I do.I edited it.Thanks.

Comment: There's 11 cubes, so 11 moves to put them on the desk, and another 11 moves to put them back again, which is 22 moves (not 17), right?  (Also, this assumes the desk can have more than one cube at a time.)

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones But some of them ar ealready on the desk.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones 4 cubes are already on the desk, and to order them, you only need to move 10 of them with relation to a chosen static one

Comment: @TStancek Where is $G$ in your combination?

Comment: @TahaAkbari I missed that one, it should be between F and J. Basically, the idea was to access the bottoms, that way everything must come down, and next step is to put all in one tower starting with the bottoms, that way everything must be moved except for the I.

Comment: @TStancek I think it is better to bring $G$ befor $F$ in that way we are sure that non of the the upper cubes can move using $1$ move to the main tower because then the lower floors cube will be upper than that so we will need at least $7*2+3=17$ moves feel free to add your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in the comment section, I would probably go for a tower of this kind
$$\begin{matrix}
J\\
F\\
G\\
A\\
B\\
C\\
D\\
E\\
H\\
K\\
I
\end{matrix}
$$

To achieve that, I have to put everything from every tower somehwere else ( 7 moves) to access their bottoms, because the bottoms come first (that makes 3 moves), than put everything else in this one tower (that makes 7 moves) in original order just to be sure none of the remaining cubes can be moved from its original position. Though the maximum should be guaranteed already by forcing the bottoms to go first.